# PhantomJS Process doesn't exit

Tags: java, selenium, phantomjs

I am creating several instances of PhantomJSDriver and can make requests to websites and get the data I want.  Each instance is spawned via the following:

```
WebDriver driver = BrowserUtils.getInstance().getBrowser();
```

When I'm done I attempt to do the following:

```
    driver.close();
    driver.quit();
    driver = null;
```

However, if I open up a second terminal and run

```
myName@myBox:~/logs$ ps -e | grep phantom
 4472 pts/2    00:00:41 phantomjs
 4524 pts/2    00:00:32 phantomjs
 4787 pts/2    00:00:18 phantomjs
 4808 pts/2    00:00:19 phantomjs
```

They are just sitting there.  They never go away.  Ideas?

Edit 1: Added some more code for clarification

```
WebDriver driver = BrowserUtils.getInstance().getBrowser();
        try {
            driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            driver.get("https://my-web-site.com/");
            // Do lots of things
            } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.log(e);
        } finally {
            BrowserUtils.getInstance().reset();
            driver.close();
            driver.quit();
            driver = null;
        }
```

Comment: ideally anyone of the close or quit methods should work. Did u had some unclosed versions earlier?

Comment: Possible the `driver.quit()` was never being called since test failed or something like that. Do you make sure it is being called no matter what happens to the tests?

Comment: I have it in a try/catch/finally so that no matter what happens it's called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check your code for quit, exit calls, even on.error catches. Add the missing one.

Also, if that is ok, consider the following bug https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10845
in case you have nvidia video adapter (I have this problem even in PhantomJS 1.9.8)
If you have nvidia, please upgrade the driver, or select just one of the two video adapters you have and not auto-select.

Good luck

Comment: I'll continue looking.  However, I know it's not the video card

Comment: After looking through my logs a bit more.  There was a Element not found timeout error that wasn't being caught and keeping the service alive.  Now I can fire 6 instances at once!